# Let undefined property be null value in Laravel

Tags: laravel, object, properties, request, undefined

Is there any way to make object undefined property become null value?

Because laravel request object will auto make undefined property become null value like below.

```
$request->test; // This parameter never passed
error_log($request->test) //null
```

But when it comes to object or array it will throw errors.

```
$object->test // test is not defined
//Will throw ErrorException: Undefined property
```

What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

laravel request object uses magic method __get to actually to get the input element from the request. here is how it does things behind the scene.

```
    /**
 * Get an input element from the request.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __get($key)
{
    return Arr::get($this->all(), $key, function () use ($key) {
        return $this->route($key);
    });
}
```

you can use the __get magic method to avoid undefined property access exception as follows

```
    /**
 * check if attribute exists or not, if not exists return null.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return mixed|null
 */
public function __get($key)
{
    return isset($this->{$key})?$this->{$key}:null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `isset($your_object->its_propery)`. isset() will return `false` if got undefined else it return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `Request` class has the magic method `__get` ([check this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)) which will return `null` if the parameter that you are asking for doesn't exist on the request parameters.

So for example `$request->test;` won't be interpreted as "go and grab the `test` attribute of that object" but instead will run the `__get($value)` method, of that Class, which will check if that `$value` (that is in this case `test`) exists in the request parameters, if yes, the method will return that value, if not, will return null, where instead, if you don't create/have the magic method `__get` in your class, PHP will just check if that `test` is an attribute of your class, otherwise will return `undefined`.

You can always check if something is `undefined` using `isset($value)` function